# How to upload Image on selection to a custom api and return the url to record

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a SimpleForm inside an edit component, in which I have an ImageInput. My goal is to upload the image when selecting it and assigning the URL returned by the response of /upload API into the record object and save the JSON payload with the correct URL instead of localhost.

```
function CategoryEdit() {
    return (
      <Edit
        title={<Title page="Category" title="name" />}
        actions={<CategoryEditActions />}
        aside={<Aside />}
      >
        <SimpleForm t`your text`oolbar={<CustomToolbar />}>
          <TextInput source="id" disabled label="ID" fullWidth />
          <TextInput source="name" required fullWidth />
          <TextInput source="description" multiline fullWidth />
          <ImageInput source="image" label=" Image" accept="image/*">
            <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
          </ImageInput>
        </SimpleForm>
      </Edit>
    );
}
```

I have tried to solve it using onDrop, but I am not able to modify the edit record manually inside onDrop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that these operations are best done in the DataProvider, where you can upload an image, and then modify the record before submitting. There is a similar example [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#handling-file-uploads) but there the image is loaded as part of the record.

Comment: But for me there are different API's for uploading the image and POST the record data, I want to return the URL in the response of the upload image to the record data.

Comment: You can implement the call to upload images yourself via fetch, axios or in another way,
and then add the resulting URL to your record before submitting.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example code for solution 1, it would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `FileInput` component, fixed by creating a `FileInputAsync` component.

Solution 1 : From scratch

- Create component to select your images and show selected image.
- When image is added, send to your api with fetch or another one
- Add the result into your form data with `useInput`

This is a simple approch example to start to resolve your problem with react admin

```
const ImageInputAsync = ({source, ...rest} : ImageInputProps) => {
    const { field: { onChange, value } } = useInput({source, ...rest});

    const onChangeHandler = (e:any) => {
        // Get file from the input
        const file = ...

        if(file.length){
            // Validate your image (size,mime,...), if error, notify and remove image from the input

            // Send it with fetch, axios, data provider or someone else
            const res = ...

            // If no error, change data in your state
            if(..ok..){
                onChange({id: res.id, ...})
            } 
            else{
                console.log("oops error...")
            }
        }
        else{
            onChange({id: res.id, ...})
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" onChange={onChangeHandler}>
            <img src={`http://localhost:9999/public/file/${id}`} alt="..."> 
        </>
    )
}
```

Solution 2 : From `ImageInput`component

- Duplicate ImageInput source code
- Override it to upload when image dropped and add it to form data like in the solution 1

In all cases, for user experience, mind to disable form submit button during uploading and show error and info notifications

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example code for solution 1, it would be grateful.

Comment: I edited the post to add example